VBA tool to extract data from large number of log files from a folder
Extract data from logs and put on a Sheet(Column A and B) since other column already have formula
Apologies Im still noob in vba coding. Seeking help to improve vba code to extract data from large number of logs and put it on a existing worksheet
Sub Extract_Data()

   Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   Dim R1 As Range, xCel As Range
   Dim Checking As Boolean
   Dim Rng As Range
   
   Set MySource = MyObj.GetFolder("D:\Log_Files_Folder\")
   
   
   Checking = False
   For Each file In MySource.Files
      If InStr(1, file.Value, "Start") <> 0 Then
         Checking = True
         
      End If
      
      If Checking = True And InStr(1, file.Value, "Correct") <> 0 Then
         xCel.Offset(0, 3).Value = xCel.Value
        
        
      End If
      
      If Checking = True And InStr(1, file.Value, "Correct") <> 0 Then
        xCel.Offset(0, 2).Value = xCel.Offset(0, -1).Value
      
      End If
        
                  
      If InStr(1, xCel.Value, "End") <> 0 Then
         Checking = False
      End If
      
   Next xCel

Set Rng = Range("B:B")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Rng
    .Value = Evaluate(Replace("If(@="""","""",Trim(@))", "@", .Address))
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    
End Sub

Logs Sample

Expected Result Sample


Hi.  What is your issue?

hello....need to Extract data from logs and put on a Sheet(Column A and B) since other column of worksheet already have formula

Can you show the log contents, the expected results, what your issue is in getting this.  What you want to get "Extract data from logs and put on a Sheet(Column A and B)" doesn't really show what you want.

hi i have update the question with image of logs sample and sample excel file result :)

This code makes absolutely no sense (and doesn't compile). Issues I see: (1) You never assign anything to MyObj - I assume that you want to use a FileSystemObject? (2) a file has no property value - if you want to work on the content of a file, you need to read it's content first. (3) You don't assign anything to the range object xCel ( with other words, you will need to tell VBA which cell is represented by xCel). (4) you start your loop with For Each file... but end it with Next xCel.

Apologies I have a little VB knowledge and will took me very long time to figure out everything that's why im seeking help here

You need to do a bit of research on as @FunThomas says, the filesystemobject here will become a very good friend.  Also, look at ways of reading text files. I think the legacy data controls (don't quote me) enable you to mess about within excel from a text file.  You will learn a lot researching this method and will be used more than once i imagine :)      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object   and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/textstream-object

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
